# Defining a class object with type() : Why can't I use the name of an attribute meant to be deepcopied?

Tags: python, django, attributeerror

**For some reasons I had to create a form class in Django by using the `type()` function.**

The return statement of my function generator (`makeFurnitureForm()`) looked like this :

```
    return (type("FurnitureForm",
                 (forms.BaseForm, form_utils.forms.BetterBaseForm,),
                 {"_fieldsets" : dic, "base_fields" : fields,
                  "_fieldset_collection" : None, '_row_attrs' : {}}))
```

The class object I create inherits from two other classes.
Here is the constructor of one of them : [form_utils.forms.BetterBaseForm](https://github.com/carljm/django-form-utils/blob/master/form_utils/forms.py#L191)

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._fieldsets = deepcopy(self.base_fieldsets)
        self._row_attrs = deepcopy(self.base_row_attrs)
        self._fieldset_collection = None
        super(BetterBaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Everything works fine with my code, but on a previous version, I used a code like this :

```
    return (type("FurnitureForm",
                 (forms.BaseForm, form_utils.forms.BetterBaseForm,),
                 {"base_fieldsets" : dic, "base_fields" : fields}))
```

Since `_fieldsets` and `_fieldset_collection` are explicitly defined and set in the `BetterBaseForm` constructor by deepcopying `base_fieldsets` attribute and assigning `None` value, I didn't understand why I got `AttributeError`s when trying to access `_fieldsets` and `_fieldset_collection` attribute of an instance (when rendering my django page for instance).

#### Here are my questions :

1. Doesn't `type()` calls base classes` constructors, and don't these constructors define and set attributes properly?
2. Why did I have to explicitly set these attributes by myself?
3. Why didn't I got an `AttributeError` when the constructor tries to
   access an attribute (`row_attrs` for instance) during the `type()`
   call? (I got one when trying to access it later though).

I use my `makeFurnitureForm()` like this in my django view :

```
return (render(request,'main/devis-bis.html', {"form" : (makeFurnitureForm())()}))
```

The class object is directly passed to a view, and then to a template to be rendered.

## EDIT : Traceback and code.

Example with this return :

```
    return (type("FurnitureForm",
                 (forms.BaseForm, form_utils.forms.BetterBaseForm,),
                 {"base_fieldsets" : dic, "base_fields" : fields,
                  "_fieldset_collection" : None, '_row_attrs' : {}}))
```

I also found out I directly pass a class object to the render() function, I don't understand why it even works because it expects an instance. I corrected it in the `render()` call.

```
File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in __getitem__
  141.             field = self.fields[name]

During handling of the above exception ('fieldsets'), another exception occurred:

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  883.                     current = current[bit]

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in __getitem__
  144.                 "Key %r not found in '%s'" % (name, self.__class__.__name__))

During handling of the above exception ("Key 'fieldsets' not found in 'FurnitureForm'"), another exception occurred:

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Code/web/demenhouse/htdocs/main/views.py" in secondform
  69.         return (render(request,'main/devis-bis.html', {"form" : makeFurnitureForm()}))

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  97.         return template.render(context, request)

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  95.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  206.                     return self._render(context)

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  173.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  69.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  161.                 values = self.sequence.resolve(context, True)

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  709.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  850.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  891.                         current = getattr(current, bit)

File "/nfs/2013/v/vmonteco/Envs/demenhouse/lib/python3.5/site-packages/form_utils/forms.py" in fieldsets
  253.                 self, self._fieldsets)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /devisbis/1679091c5a880faf6fb5e6087eb1b2dc/
Exception Value: 'FurnitureForm' object has no attribute '_fieldsets'
```

Comment: `type` will create the class. The `__init__` method won't be called until you initialise the class.

Comment: Can you show us the full tracebacks of the errors you see, and please add some code that shows how you are trying to access those attributes. I suspect you are getting confused between what `type()` does and when `__init__` is called. It *could* be that you do create an instance of the form here (directly or having Django do it), but a traceback could easily make it clear what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > Doesn't `type()` calls base classes` constructors, and don't these constructors define and set attributes properly?

   You are looking at *initialisers*, not constructors, hence the name `__init__`. These are automatically called when an instance is created. `type()` doesn't call these, because you are not producing an instance, you are producing a *class*.

   Once you call the resulting class to create an instance, *then* the `__init__` method is called.
2. > Why did I have to explicitly set these attributes by myself?

   I don't know, you don't show how you are creating an instance, or any other code showing your error. If you are expecting those attributes to exist on the *class*, then your assumption there is wrong.
3. > Why didn't I got an `AttributeError` when the constructor tries to access an attribute (row_attrs for instance) during the type() call? (I got one when trying to access it later though).

   Again, `type()` produces a new class, not an instance, and `__init__` is not called at this time.

You should not need to add those attributes to your *class* namespace if the `__init__` method will add them to your *instance* namespace.

I must note that the [`forms.BaseForm.__init__` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L72-L95) is *not* designed to cooperate with other classes coming later in the MRO; it never calls `super().__init__()`. If you do create an instance of your new class, the `form_utils.forms.BetterBaseForm.__init__()` method will *not* be called, unless you were to swap the order of your two base classes:

```
return type(
    "FurnitureForm", (form_utils.forms.BetterBaseForm, forms.BaseForm,),
    {"base_fieldsets" : dic, "base_fields" : fields})
```

That's because with `BetterBaseForm` listed first, it'll have it's `__init__` be called, and the `super(BetterBaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` line in that method will then call `BaseForm.__init__()`.

Reading your traceback I do note that you *never create an instance*. You should always create an instance of a form class, and optionally pass in `request.POST` to pre-populate the fields and validate the form input.

So instead of:

```
return (render(request,'main/devis-bis.html', {"form" : makeFurnitureForm()}))
```

use

```
return render(request,'main/devis-bis.html', {"form" : makeFurnitureForm()()})
```

Note the extra `()`. You probably want to check if the form is *valid* at some point, however, so you'd use this:

```
form_class = makeFurnitureForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # ...
        # process data, redirect somewhere
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

else:
    form = form_class()

return render(request,'main/devis-bis.html', {"form" : form})
```

Comment: Your explanations are pretty clear. It helped me a lot to understand the problem. I also came myself to the same conclusion with someone's help on IRC about the fact I directly pass a class object to `render()` function. **replacing the class object with an instance works, and it even corrects other problems I didn't understand before**. I edited my post at the same time you were editing yours. :) Thank you for your answer, it was really helpful.